# Change rails version used by rvm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

Here are my local gems :

```
$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (4.0.0, 3.2.14)
actionpack (4.0.0, 3.2.14)
activemodel (4.0.0, 3.2.14)
activerecord (4.0.0, 3.2.14)
activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
activeresource (3.2.14)
activesupport (4.0.0, 3.2.14)
arel (4.0.0, 3.0.2)
atomic (1.1.13)
builder (3.1.4, 3.0.4)
bundler (1.3.5)
bundler-unload (1.0.1)
erubis (2.7.0)
hike (1.2.3)
i18n (0.6.5)
journey (1.0.4)
json (1.8.0)
mail (2.5.4)
mime-types (1.24)
minitest (4.7.5)
multi_json (1.7.9)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.5.2, 1.4.5)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-ssl (1.3.3)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rails (3.2.14)
railties (4.0.0, 3.2.14)
rake (10.1.0)
rdoc (3.12.2)
rubygems-bundler (1.2.2)
rubygems-update (2.0.7)
rvm (1.11.3.8)
sprockets (2.10.0, 2.2.2)
sprockets-rails (2.0.0)
thor (0.18.1)
thread_safe (0.1.2)
tilt (1.4.1)
treetop (1.4.15)
tzinfo (0.3.37)
```

But when I type `rails -v` I get this :

```
 $ rails -v
Rails 4.0.0
 $ which rails
/Users/polonium/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/rails
```

How can I specify rvm to use rails version 3.2.14 ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can create a new rails app with a particular rails version, like this:

```
rails _3.2.14_ new myApp
```

Comment: Oh yes! That was perfect. Thanks.

Comment: That´s a fix to create a rails app with a specific rails version, but is not a fix for the original problem with rvm.. @mpapis answer points exactly to the original question.

Comment: That doesn't work for me: `$ rails _3.2.14_ new myApp
/Users/7stud/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:296:in 'to_specs': Could not find 'railties' (= 3.2.14) - did find: [railties-4.0.0] (Gem::LoadError)`

Answer (score 50):

> How can I specify rvm to use rails version 3.2.14 ?

rvm has nothing to do with rails.  rvm is used to manage multiple ruby installations.  And each of your ruby installations can be associated with multiple gemsets.  For instance, say you have ruby 1.9.3 installed and you created two gemsets for ruby 1.9.3: gemsetA and gemsetB.  If you tell rvm to use ruby 1.9.3 with gemsetA, that means:

1. Your ruby programs will be executed by ruby 1.9.3.
2. Your ruby programs can require any gem in gemsetA (which then allows your program to use the methods (or classes) defined in gemsetA), but any gems in gemsetB cannot be seen by your ruby program.

Here's a concrete example:

```
~$ rvm list

rvm rubies

   ruby-1.8.7-p370 [ i686 ]
 * ruby-1.9.3-p194 [ x86_64 ]
=> ruby-2.0.0-p0 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.0.0-p247 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default


~$ rvm use 1.9.3-p194
Using /Users/7stud/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194
```

.

```
~$ rvm gemset list   (This lists only the gemsets for the current ruby version)

gemsets for ruby-1.9.3-p194 (found in /Users/7stud/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194)
=> (default)
   global
   programming
   rails3tutorial
   rails4

~$ rvm gemset use programming
Using ruby-1.9.3-p194 with gemset programming
```

After I do that, my ruby programs will be executed by ruby 1.9.3 and any gems in the programming gemset can be required into my ruby program.  You can use a shortcut to perform both those commands in one step:

```
rvm use ruby 1.9.3-p194@programming
```

You just combine the ruby version and the gemset with an '@' between them.

> But when I type rails -v I get this :
>
> ```
> $ rails -v
> Rails 4.0.0
> ```

That's because the current gemset contains the gem for rails 4.0.0.   If you want to see `$ rails -v` output `Rails 3.2.14`, then you need to tell rvm to switch to a gemset that contains the rails 3.2.14 gem.

However, you can make rvm automatically switch to the proper rails version and gemset for your rails project.  In your Gemfile, add a comment after the ruby version:

```
ruby '2.0.0'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial4_gems
```

Then whenever you switch to the directory containing your rails project, rvm will automatically switch the current ruby to ruby 2.0.0 and the current gemset to railstutorial4_gems.  If you change directories out of your rails app, rvm will change the current ruby and the current gemset back to what they were.

I'm just a rails beginner, but here are the steps I use to create a new project, which are straight out of the railstutorial book (http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book)

1)

```
.../rails_projects$ rvm use <ruby version here>@<new gemset name here> --create 

e.g.

.../rails_projects$ rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp_gemset --create
```

2)

```
.../rails_projects$ gem install rails --version 3.2.14
```

Because the current gemset is the myapp gemset, that command installs the rails 3.2.14 gem into the myapp gemset.

3)

```
.../rails_projects$ rails new myapp
.../rails_projects$ cd myapp
```

The current gemset is still myapp_gemset.

4)

```
.../rails_projects/myapp$ rails -v
Rails 3.2.14
```

In case anyone was wondering what the heck the following two gemsets are all about:

```
gemsets for ruby-1.9.3-p194 (found in /Users/7stud/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194)

=> (default)
   global
```

rvm creates those two gemsets for every ruby version you install.  After you install a ruby version, if you don't create a gemset yourself for that ruby version, and you install a gem, then the gem goes into the (default) gemset.  And, if you want all your gemsets to contain a certain gem, you can switch to the global gemset and install the gem there.

**Update:** -------

To maintain compatibility with other ruby version managers, you can specify the ruby version and gemset name for your project in a different file rather than in the Gemfile:

```
$ cd ~/rails_projects/myapp

~/rails_projects/myapp$ echo 2.0.0 > .ruby-version
~/rails_projects/myapp$ echo myapp_gemset > .ruby-gemset
```

You'll still get the same automatic ruby version and gemset switching when you `cd` into your project's directory. See the rvm docs [here](https://rvm.io/workflow/projects#supported-files).

Comment: That is a very nicely written answer. Especially the part about "In your Gemfile, add a comment after the Ruby version". I did not know rvm would do that automatic switching between versions.

Comment: A rare and flawless diamond in the rough of StackOverflow. Thank you 7stud. Thank you.

Answer (score 23):

the path you found `/Users/polonium/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/rails` is not proper path you would found in standard rvm installation while doing proper use of rvm, what you would see should be: `/Users/polonium/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/rails`

to get it working properly try this flow:

```
rvm use 2.0.0
rvm gemset empty
rvm use @rails3 --create 
gem install rails -v "~>3.2"
rvm use @rails4 --create
gem install rails -v "~>4"
```

this way now you can switch between this two rails installations with:

```
rvm use 2.0.0@rails3
rails -v             # rails 3.2...
rvm use 2.0.0@rails4
rails -v             # rails 4.0...
```

Comment: If the gemset does not already  exist do : rvm use @rails3 --create

Answer (score 5):

**you should do: gem install 'rails' -v '3.2.13'**

**You should use a clean gemset, if you are using rvm, you can try:**

rvm gemset create 
rvm gemset use

**Now you have a clean gemset, it's time to install rails,**

gem install rails -v '3.2.13'

**and then create a rails app,**

rails new app_name

Answer (score 0):

"railties (4.0.0," is the problem you have. I guess it was installed by mistake?

Uninstall that version using, gem uninstall railties, and then picking the option with 4.0.0.

Now the command "rails -v" will return your expected version which is "3.2.14"

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to check the global gemset by first making sure you are in the ruby version you intend to use

```
$ruby -v
```

Then switch to the global gemset (the global gemset applys to all of the gemsets so be sure to keep it clean and universal...or global, hence the name)

```
$rvm gemset use global
```

After that check the gem list for gems that can affect it like the "railties" gem that Harsha mentioned by typing

```
$gem list
```

Sometimes the global gemset can be populated by an accidental gem that will affect all other gemsets. If you find a misplaced gem you can uninstall it simply with

```
$gem uninstall examplegem
```

or for a specific version of that gem pass in the -v with the version in quotes

```
$gem uninstall examplegem -v"3.2.1"
```

And read 7stud's comment on creating and using RVM for changing between different gemsets.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the version of Rails you want, with:

```
$ gem install rails --version 3.2.14
```

And then create an app with that version:

```
$ rails _3.2.14_ new myapp
```

Finally, you can check it out the content of the "Gemfile" to corroborate:

```
...
 gem 'rails', '3.2.14'
...
```