# Created Ruby Gemset with specific Rails Version not shown in rvm list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I was following along with the directions [here](http://railsapps.github.io/updating-rails.html) under the section **Rails Installation With RVM Gemsets**

Per the directions above I created a new rvm gemset:

```
$ rvm use ruby-2.2.1@rails4.2.1 --create
$ gem install rails
```

The rails installation was successful, running

```
$ rails -v
```

returns rails version 4.2.1 as expected.

Next I ran

```
$ rvm list
```

it returns my list of gemsets as:

```
rvm rubies

  ruby-2.0.0-p247 [ x86_64 ]
  ruby-2.0.0-p598 [ x86_64 ]
  ruby-2.1.1 [ x86_64 ]
  =* ruby-2.2.1 [ x86_64 ]
```

Why isn't `ruby-2.2.1@rails4.2.1` one of my gemsets? I thought I was specifically creating a ruby 2.2.1 gemset with rails 4.2.1, which would then also allow me to keep a separate ruby 2.2.1 gemset with previous versions of rails?

Comment: Some more tips here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18290080/change-rails-version-used-by-rvm/18290486#18290486

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[rvm list](https://rvm.io/rubies/list) shows the list of Ruby versions installed, not the gemsets. Try [rvm gemset list](https://rvm.io/gemsets/listing) to see a list of the gemsets.

Comment: Wow, that's embarrassing. Thanks.