# System can't see Rails or other gems says "Rails is not currently installed on this system"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rvm

System: OSX 10.9.5, Rails 4.0.12

After cloning a repo for a demo app (Ruby 2.1.5, Rails 4.1.0), I used rvm to install and then switch to an older version of Ruby, so I could run the demo app. I had some issues running the demo app, so I went back to my main project app (Ruby 2.2.4, Rails 4.0.12), tried to run `rails s` and got:

```
Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

    $ sudo gem install rails

You can then rerun your "rails" command.
```

Well that's just silly. Rails was just here a moment ago. I tried switching gemsets within Ruby 2.2.4, even closing terminal in between, but still Rails was "not installed". These are my gemsets:

```
gemsets for ruby-2.0.0-p481 (found in /Users/localflavor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481)
=> (default)
   global

gemsets for ruby-2.1.5 (found in /Users/localflavor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5)
=> (default)
   global

gemsets for ruby-2.2.1 (found in /Users/localflavor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1)
=> (default)
   global    

gemsets for ruby-2.2.2 (found in /Users/localflavor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2)
=> (default)
   global

gemsets for ruby-2.2.4 (found in /Users/localflavor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4)
=> (default)
   global

gemsets for ruby-2.3.0 (found in /Users/localflavor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0)
=> (default)
   global
```

The gems included in ruby2.2.4@default:

```
$ gem list
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
bigdecimal (default: 1.2.6)
gem-wrappers (1.2.7)
io-console (default: 0.4.3)
json (default: 1.8.1)
minitest (5.4.3)
power_assert (0.2.2)
psych (default: 2.0.8)
rake (default: 10.4.2)
rdoc (default: 4.2.0)
rvm (1.11.3.9)
test-unit (3.0.8)
```

The gems included in ruby-2.2.4@global

```
$ gem list
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
bigdecimal (default: 1.2.6)
gem-wrappers (1.2.7)
io-console (default: 0.4.3)
json (default: 1.8.1)
minitest (5.4.3)
power_assert (0.2.2)
psych (default: 2.0.8)
rake (default: 10.4.2)
rdoc (default: 4.2.0)
rvm (1.11.3.9)
test-unit (3.0.8)
```

Rails, where are you? I've tried `rvm get master`, reinstalling ruby 2.2.4, openssl, and bundler. I've tried every solution that seemed relevant from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7788946/rails-keeps-telling-me-that-its-not-currently-installed). All of this to no avail.

Interestingly enough, I am also unable to install the latest version of Ruby (2.4.0).

```
$ rvm install ruby 2.4.0
ruby-2.4.0 - #removing src/ruby-2.4.0..
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.9/x86_64/ruby-2.4.0.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Certificates in '/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem' are already up to date.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/localflavor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.4.0 - #downloading ruby-2.4.0, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-2.4.0 - #extracting ruby-2.4.0 to /Users/localflavor/.rvm/src/ruby-2.4.0....
ruby-2.4.0 - #configuring...................................................................
ruby-2.4.0 - #post-configuration.
ruby-2.4.0 - #compiling....................
Error running '__rvm_make -j 1',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/localflavor/.rvm/log/1487187741_ruby-2.4.0/make.log
configuring pty
configuring racc/cparse
configuring rbconfig/sizeof
configuring readline
configuring ripper
configuring rubyvm
configuring sdbm
configuring socket
configuring stringio
configuring strscan
configuring syslog
configuring zlib
exts.mk:1471: *** commands commence before first target.  Stop.
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
++ return 2
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

I'm assuming Rails is here, just not being seen. Just like bundler and openssl. Something is up and I don't know where else to look. How can I find it and get it back in action?

---

## **UPDATE**

Though my SSL issues are still unresolved, I was able to do this workaround to get Rails up and running again (thanks [Kevin-T](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7576882/kevin-t)!)

Since Rails was missing from both gemsets for ruby 2.2.4 (thanks [7stud](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42259234/5009528) for the gem list pointers), I needed to reinstall it. But I was getting this error when I ran `gem install rails -v 4.0.12`

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::Exception)
    Unable to require openssl, install OpenSSL and rebuild ruby (preferred) or use non-HTTPS sources
```

So I chose option 2: use a non-HTTPS source. In order to do that, I ran `gem source` to confirm that my source was `https`:

```
*** CURRENT SOURCES ***

https://rubygems.org/
```

I added the new `http` version with `gem source --add http://rubygems.org` :

```
https://rubygems.org is recommended for security over http://rubygems.org

Do you want to add this insecure source? [yn]  y  <-- I said yes
http://rubygems.org added to sources
```

I checked that it was added with `gem source`:

```
*** CURRENT SOURCES ***

https://rubygems.org/
http://rubygems.org <-- the new one
```

Then removed the `https` one with `gem source --remove https://rubygems.org/`:

```
https://rubygems.org/ removed from sources
```

At this point, running `gem install rails -v 4.0.12` worked. Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381725/how-to-make-no-ri-no-rdoc-the-default-for-gem-install)  to install without the bulky documentation.

Answer (score 0):

> Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest
>   version, simply type:
>
> ```
> $ sudo gem install rails
> ```
>
> You can then rerun your "rails" command.

---

> Well that's just silly. Rails was just here a moment ago.

First a warning: NEVER use `sudo` with rvm.

With rvm, there are two things that you need to pay attention to:

1. The ruby version.
2. The gemset.

A gemset is like a self contained package with certain gems in it.  To *see* those gems, you have to be *using* that gemset.  If you are using a different gemset, then you will *see* different gems.

In order to verify that a gem is contained in the gemset that is currently selected, you can do this:

```
$ gem list
```

For general instructions on how to use rvm wtih rails and various gemsets, see here:

[Change rails version used by rvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18290080/change-rails-version-used-by-rvm/18290486)

> Interestingly enough, I am also unable to install the latest version
>   of Ruby (2.4.0).

Your output shows that rvm is having trouble compiling `zlib`.  It appears that the rbenv crowd is also having some problems compiling zlib on OSX.  You might want to try their fix:

https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/issues/832

Answer (score 0):

Rvm had [this issue](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/3748) not too long ago. It predates ruby 2.4.0, but maybe you're getting the same problem here? I suspect you're running an older install if you're running OS X 10.9. The solution recommended on that issue is to simply update your rvm with

```
rvm get master
```

I would try running that and then retrying your rvm commands.

Sidenote: pgp verification is now mandatory with rvm, so you may need to run

```
gpg2 --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3
```

first.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on gpg2! @Glyoko